# Can I create a CRL distribution point using EasyRsa?

Tags: certificate, ca

For one my school projects I must build a CA and run various scenarios one of which is to distribute a Certificate Revocation List. The problem is that EasyRsa has no obvious functionality to tweak in order to specify a URI for a distribution point attached to the signed certificate.
Any ideas please since neither the official repo of EasyRsa on gitHub provides a solution nor OpenSSL is preferrable (I can't start over again :-))?

Answer (score 0):

Add your URL to the x509-types/COMMON file which is included in easyRSA

You'll see the default contents of the file tell you how to use this for a CRL and an AIA:

https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/blob/master/easyrsa3/x509-types/COMMON

```
# X509 extensions added to every signed cert

# This file is included for every cert signed, and by default does nothing.
# It could be used to add values every cert should have, such as a CDP as
# demonstrated in the following example:

#crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://example.net/pki/my_ca.crl

# The authority information access extension gives details about how to access
# certain information relating to the CA.

#authorityInfoAccess = caIssuers;URI:http://example.net/pki/my_ca.crt
```